# Prove that $||f'|| \geq ||f||$

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume that $f$ has a continuous derivative on $[0,2\pi]$, that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ and that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) dt =0$. Prove that $||f'||\geq ||f||$ with equality iff $f(x)= a \cos x + b \sin x$.

If  $f(x) = a\cos x+ b\sin x$ then $||f'||=||f||$ holds but I have no idea on how to prove the converse and also I got no intution on which result should be used.

This is a second course of real analysis quiz question.

Can you please help me with this?
I am not adding much information regarding attempt but that's due to the reason that I can't think of any known result on how to approach this question and couldn't even start this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is $||f||$ defined?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Well no information regarding that is not given in question

Comment: Presumably you are using the $L^2$-norm rather than the sup norm or whatever?

Comment: With $L^2$ norm, the obvious idea would be to decompose $f$ in Fourier series and use [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Can you please answer anong the lines you mentioned in above comment . I am not able to follow Kavi Rama Murthy answer

Comment: I could, but honestly I don't see how it would be different than Kavi Rama Murthy's answer. If you can't follow his answer, the first question is: what do you know about [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)? Here $f$ is $C^1$ on $[0,2\pi]$, so it's tempting to consider a $2\pi$ periodic function $h$ such that $h(x)=f(x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$. Parseval's identity gives an expression of the $L^2$ norm of $f$ that depends only on the Fourier coefficients. And the Fourier coefficients of $f'$ depend also on the Fourier coefficients of $f$ in an easy way. Connect the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the norm here is the  $L^{2}$ norm. We have $\hat {f'} (n)=-in \hat {f} (n)$. Hence, using Parseval's identity,  $\|f'\|^{2}=\sum_n | {f'} (n)|^{2}= \sum_n n^{2}| {f} (n)|^{2}\geq \sum_n |\hat {f} (n)|^{2} =\|f||^{2}$ where I have used the  fact that the constant term is missing (since $\int f(t)dt=0$) and $n^{2} \geq 1$ for the remaining  terms.

Obviuosly, equality can hold here only when  all the coefficients correspoinding to $n$ with $|n|>1$ are zero. Hence, $f (x)=a\cos x+b\sin x$ for some $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What is $\hat{f}(n)$? I am not aware of this

Comment: The question is closely related to Fourier series. $\hat f(n) $ is the $n-$th Fourier coefficient defined by $\hat f (n)=\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-int} f(t)dt$

Comment: I am afraid apostol doesn't mentions that and I am not able to follow your solution.

Comment: I am pretty suer this question is meant to be answered using Fourier series. @No-One

Comment: So ,I will read again using Apostol